# Chance for sequence of coin tosses to end at odd number

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions

I have "solved" the following problem: however I wouldn't be able to find the numeric solution with the given formula sheet or calculator: so apparently there should be a neater way.

The question reads:

> You and a friend play the following game. You toss a fair coin until heads comes up for the first time. If the number of tosses needed is odd, you win the game.
>   Compute the probability that you win the game.

The chance that the game lasts "$n$" number of tosses is:

$$P(X=n) = \left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right)^n$$

Now I just wrote down a sequence for "winning", and using above I got the following sum:

$$\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\mathbb{N}} \left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right)^{2n}$$
Which I approximated with my calculator to be "$\tfrac{2}{3}$".

While the correct answer, this isn't the way to go: the formula sheet doesn't give any standard sequences and is **just** filled with distributions and expected values & variance for those distributions.

The distributions are Bernoulli, Binomial, Negative Binomial, Geometric (and for continuous: normal, uniform, exponential and parreti).

So I'm wondering: can I explain above problem as one of the distributions? - Or does my prof expect me to know the sum sequence by heart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your probability of winning is actually $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac12\right)^{2n+1}$, which is indeed $\frac23$. This is just a geometric series, so yes, you almost certainly are expected to know how to evaluate it. However, this problem can be solved without that knowledge. Let $p$ be your probability of winning. Then with probability $\frac12$ you win on the first toss, and with probability $\frac12$ the first toos is a tail, and in effect the game starts over with you as the second player. As second player you have a probability of $1-p$ of winning, so

$$p=\frac12+\frac12(1-p)\;.$$

Solving this for $p$ yields $p=\frac23$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a great approach, and to say that it wrong, and the correct solution is to look it up off of a formula sheet is BS.

It does sound like you are expected to know some definitions:

A Bernoulli trial.  One event, a coin flip (it could be a biased coin)

A Binomial distribution.  The number of successes after in a certain number of trials.

Negative binomial.  The number of successes before the first a certain number of failures.

The Geometric distribution.  The number of events before the first success in a sequence of trials.

Now, if you are allowed to use formula sheets, then I see no reason why you shouldn't but the definition of each distribution on said sheet.  I don't see a whole lot of value in either memorizing these formula, on in memorized this set of definitions, for that matter.